# Google One Tap doesn't work on IOS and mac Safari. Failed to open popup window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth-2.0, next.js13, google-one-tap

Google one tap doesn't work on IOS browsers and mac Safari. Google chrome, FF, android browsers etc are working fine.

Error:
`[GSI_LOGGER]: Failed to open popup window on url: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?{queryParams}. Maybe blocked by the browser?`

Script:

```
<script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client"
      defer
      data-testid="gsi-client-script"
/>
```

Code:

```
    window.google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id: publicRuntimeConfig.socials.google.auth.id,
      callback: ({ credential }) => {
        const user = decodeJwt(credential);
        if (user.email_verified) {
          const client = window.google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
            client_id: user.aud,
            scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
            hint: user.email,
            prompt: '',
            callback: ({ access_token: password }) => {
              // function is not called
            },
          });
          client.requestAccessToken(); // Error is happened after calling this
        }
      },
    });

    window.google.accounts.id.prompt();
```